# Beginner Tutorial Procedure

Tags: ros, tutorial, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If possible I'd like for experienced users to post their suggestions whether this is the correct way, and explain the commands commented as 'black magic' please.

Putting together the initial bit:

#### 1. Install ROS

follow instructions on wiki ROS tutorial.

#### 2. Create WorkSpace

`mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src`  creates src folder inside workspace folder

`cd ~/catkin_ws/src`  change directory to src folder

`catkin_init_workspace`  creates symlink (not sure what this is). creates SMakeLists in src folder

`cd ~/catkin_ws/`  change directory to workspace folder

`source opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash`  black magic

`catkin_make`  always exectue command in the workspace folder. creates build folder and devel folder with files inside

`source devel/setup.bash`  black magic

`echo "source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc`  black magic

#### 3. Create Package

`cd ~/catkin_ws/src`  change directory to src folder, where package folder must be created

`catkin_create_pkg my_pkg roscpp`  name the package and specify dependency. this creates the package folder. inside it, include folder, src folder, CMakeLists file and package file are created

#### 4. Add the code

add code inside the src folder inside the package folder. save as hello.cpp

#include 
    
    int main(int argc, char** argv){
      ros::init(argc, argv, "hello_ros");
      ros::NodeHandle nh;
      ROS_INFO_STREAM("Hello, ROS!");
    }

#### 5. Fix the CMakeLists inside the package folder

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3) 
project(book_pkg)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS   roscpp  )    

catkin_package( )

include_directories( include  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(hello src/hello.cpp) 
target_link_libraries(hello ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

#### 6. Build and run (run the package that is)

`cd ~/catkin_ws` back to workspace folder

`catkin_make` catkin specific command to build and make package

once build is successful, open new terminal, type:  `roscore`  open another terminal, type:  `rosrun my_pkg hello`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278909/beginner-tutorial-procedure/) by [finch1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33093/finch1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2018-01-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-01-05**:
This is not a question. I'm confused, what do you want help with?

**Comment by [finch1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33093/finch1/) on 2018-01-05**:
I am having issues understanding the ROS procedure. The one above worked, only after weeks of trial though. If possible I'd like for experienced users to post their suggestions whether this is the correct way, and explain the commands commented as 'black magic' please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I feel your pain on this one, it's a lot of stuff to get your head around all at the same time when you're starting out. I'll explain exactly what is going on with the three '**black magic**' commands you highlighted in your question.

`source opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash` This command executes the bash script '**opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash**' which sets the envrionment variables needed for the ros command line tools to work and means the packages installed with ros can be found.

`source devel/setup.bash` Similar to the command above this executed the bash script '**devel/setup.bash**' within the current working directory. This adds the paths for this package to the ros envrionment variables so you can find and execute the assets of packages in this workspace, for example with rosrun or roslaunch.

`echo "source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash" >> ¬/.bashrc` This command appends the line '**source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash**' to the end of the **.bashrc** file in your home folder. Why would you want to do this you ask, well the **.bashrc** file is another bash script that is automatically run every time you start a new terminal. So by adding this line the environment variables will automatically setup to use the packages in the **catkin_ws** workspace every time you open a new terminal.

Hope this explains a bit more of what's going on for you.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [finch1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33093/finch1/) on 2018-01-05**:
Hello Peter, helps a lot, big thanks for this. I tried to remove this question, its not clear, as you said. Am trying to put a tutorial together for other beginners. I'm noticing a lot getting really stuck too, especially in the beginning. Info is pretty much scattered as well. I guess I'll leave...

**Comment by [finch1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33093/finch1/) on 2018-01-05**:
... this as is, in case it helps the next one.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-01-05**:
no problem, glad it helped. if you can accept this answer then it will help other people who might have the same questions later.
Thanks.

**Comment by [finch1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33093/finch1/) on 2018-01-05**:
Thanks for the reminder, and thanks again for the explanation.